# Number SSRS pages based on grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I have a SSRS report which needs to have paging like (1 of 2, 1 of 3)

currently using

**=Globals!PageNumber & "of " & Globals!TotalPages**

gives me (1 of 5) which i know is the correct behaviour

Everywhere i see the solution is Group Properties > Page Breaks > ResetPageNumber

I dont get that option though, the pagebreak options i get are

- Between each instance
- Also at the start of a group
- Also at the end of a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what i wanted to do i edited the code itself not the rdl design which i had previously wanted to do

```
<PageBreak>
   <BreakLocation>Between<BreakLocation>
   <ResetPageNumber>True<ResetPageNumber>
<PageBreak>
```

This allowed me to print the letter's which contained a table of information at the end which was X rows long

So report could be (1 0f 1), (1 of 2, 2 of 2), (1 0f X, X 0f X)

Answer (score 1):

For the ResetPageNumber property, you need to change the property of the Group in the Advanced Mode. In the Grouping Pane at the bottom of VS, click on the down wedge/caret/arrow to change to Advanded Mode.

[image]

Select the table, then, in the Grouping Pane at the bottom of VS, select the Group that you want the Reset on. The Group properties will show in the properties window with the PageBreak options that include the ResetPageNumber property.

[image]

Comment: Under my Row Groups i just get two rows, both labeled (static)

Comment: @AidanWard - can you show what the RowGroups are for the group that you are getting the Group Properties for ("the pagebreak options i get are...")?